# mail() function won't send more than one line

Tags: php, html, email

Okay so I'm making a website and want to send out a no reply email. If I send a message that's between one paragraph, it sends fine. as soon as I try sending a message that's longer than one paragraph, the message never reaches my inbox. When I run the following code, it runs as true yet the message never reaches my inbox.

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "email sent successfully";
}
```

Anyone have issues with this? I tried contacting my hosting provider and they had no idea why.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
                $to = "VElicted8008@gustr.com";
$subject = "Welcome To PROJECTNAME (FAQ Included)";

$message = '<p>Hello YouTuber! </p><p>Hello YouTuber! </p>
<p>To begin, here are some FAQs: </p>
<p>......</p>
<p>Thank you again for registering! </p>';

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <no-reply@project-name.com>' . "\r\n";
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "email sent successfully";
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you running from a local installation? (i.e localhost)? Have you checked your spam box? Is your domain/ip blacklisted?

Comment: no, i'm running this off of a regular shared hosting account. I've checked my spam box, tried sending it to multiple email providers, and still nothing. Domain blacklist?

Comment: just a note about `mail`'s return value: `mail` generally never ever returns anything useful. I have had it fail to send a message countless times for any number of reasons, and every single time it returned true.

Comment: @TechTubeCentral [**Check this link out for blacklist**](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

Comment: Spare yourself some headache and use PHPMailer or other SMTP based library to send mails. At least it will give some debug info and will return true if it is really sent, not when it's hopefully maybe sent.

Comment: so I found out that my webhost isn't processing messages with the mail function if they contain an email address withing the message itself. I tried using codeignighters email class that uses sendmail and it says "Unable to open a socket to Sendmail". Any ideas for alternatives?